# Improving Visualization: Cartesian Distortion in D3.js ( fisheye plugin )

Tags: d3.js, distortion, cartesian, scaletransform, fisheye

In [this amazing visualization](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/09/13/fashion-week-editors-picks/) from the NY-Times team, you can see the [Cartesian Disortion](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#cartesian) in action.

In one case, i think that this visualization can be improved.

As you can see in this picture, the last image will be bigger if the cursor is on the left site of the picture, than it would be if it is centered. (crosshair shows the cursor position)

[image]

As a user, you would expect to see the **biggest image when you are exactly over it**. You have this effect in the middle of this visualization.

```
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t0pbqe3j/6/
```

**The question**:

How can i modify the algorithm or the focus-logic to display every section/image at its maximum width when the cursor is in the middle of it ?

Comment: So what's the question? If this is a feature request/enhancement, you're posting it in the wrong place.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i have added a clear question, now :)